# SQL Server date range search issue

Tags: node.js

I have a MS SQL Server DateTime field, and Im trying to search all records that are in between a date range:

```
mySqlString = "select * from users where signupDate >=@from and signupdate <=@to"
```

The two variables containing the date range come with format MM/dd/yyyy (dataFrom and dataTo, so Im replacing @from and @to at the string as follows:

```
    datefrom = new Date(dataFrom);
    dateto = new Date(dataTo);
    req.input('from', sql.DateTime, datefrom )
    req.input('to', sql.DateTime, dateto )
```

But I do not get any result.

What's the best approach to get this working properly?

Comment: If you have a DateTime field, you may want to consider adding "23:59:59" to the "TO" field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use CONVERT to accommodate your SQL query to your input format. In your case its format 101: select convert(varchar, getdate(), 101) ---> mm/dd/yyyy

So your query should look like

```
where (signupdate >= CONVERT(date, @from, 101)) AND (signupdate <= CONVERT(date, @to, 101))
```

This way you won't worry about the time of the stored date

```
req.input('from', sql.Date, (dataFrom))
req.input('to', sql.Date, (dataTo))
```

Assuming you checked if dataFrom and dataTo have valid dates.

Comment: thank you this worked